# Prompt to download a stream of multiple files as one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming there's a server storing multiple files (not necessarily text documents):
`http://<server>/<path>/file0001.txt ... http://<server>/<path>/file9999.txt`

If user was to download all of those files as one, how would I do it in javascript?

Normally user would have to download 9999 files and join them on his drive.
How can I prompt a download of a file and stream the data of multiple files while javascript gets them, just like it's a stream of one, big file.

I imagine it would be something like this (excuse me for lack of javascript, just trying to explain):

```
With (download prompt of 'onefile.txt') as connection:
While connection is open:
    For file in file_list:
        get file
        return file.contents
    connection close
```

Downloading each file and storing it in memory until the last one is retrieved is not a good idea, since overall size of that file can be quite big.

I'm wondering if that's even possible. I can write it in python, but that's another story. I wanted to make it a javascript function on a website.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just combine them all server side w/ python and then stream the resulting blob?  `http://<server>/<path>/aggregator.py`, have that file combine the files and output headers telling the browser to download the result as a text file or whatever.

Comment: I wanted to do it originally, yes, and I will if it's not possible with Javascript. I wish to make a website with a purpose, to be available to people freely online, a tool to do something. I can't host that many files if it's a public service.

Comment: I see, that makes sense.  Your best bet then would probably be to download each file with ajax, read the files into a hidden canvas and then use something like https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js  or https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js to allow the user to save the canvas as a blob.

Comment: What if each file is eg. mpeg2 transport stream, 5mb each and concaternated result.ts is 5gb? That can't fit in a canvas, can it? :o

Comment: Oh, no...that will not work.  Most browsers (everything but chrome?) will choke on that if you try to do it because they won't let javascript applications use that much memory.  For something like that, you almost have to do it server side.  You don't have to store the files you're generating though, just send the files from the server 1 at a time as part of the same stream.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but the server/host upload speed is the limit. Someone could easily break or stop the service. I'm surprised javascript can't just create a "virtual localhost connection" where it uses some generator to "yield" the contents of each file...

Comment: Don't do anything with canvas... Use [jszip](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip) to add all files into one. Then if it gets really large then use jszip together with [streamSaver](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js). Otherwise [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) will do just fine. StreamSaver.js only works in Blink (chrome & opera)

Comment: Oh, miss read - you want to concatenate all files into one large. Then jszip isn't necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm surprised javascript can't just create a "virtual localhost connection" where it uses some generator to "yield" the contents of each file...

Well, if you use a service worker then you can manipulate the response and give it a readableStream which you can "yield" the content of each file...

---

This is what the streamSaver dose internally but takes away all hassle...
I will show you an example using es6 and [StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js)

It's not tested it's just a ruffly idea.
This will consume very little memory, but it's limited to only Blink ATM if you wanna use StreamSaver

```
let download = Promise.coroutine(function* (files) {
    const fileStream = streamSaver.createWriteStream('onefile.txt')
    const writeStream = fileStream.getWriter()

    // Later you will be able to just simply do
    // yield res.body.pipeTo(fileStream) instead of pumping

    for (let file of files) {
        let res = yield fetch(file)
        let reader = res.body.getReader()

        let pump = () => reader.read()
        .then(({ value, done }) => !done &&
            // Write one chunk, then get the next one
            writeStream.write(value).then(pump)
        )

        yield pump()
    }

    // Close the stream when you are done writing
    writeStream.close()
}

download([
    'http://<server>/<path>/file0001.txt',
    'http://<server>/<path>/file9999.txt'
]).then(() => {
    alert('all done')
})
```

Comment: It could be swapped out with yield and bluebird-coroutine for example but i used async to let it be up do you wanna do (async/await is not yet available) unless you use a transpiler

Comment: This looks really interesting and I'll totally try this out. I don't really know javascript, so I'll have to learn this part because this is literally the only function I need on that website. I'll report back soon :)

Comment: One question, can I do it in `<script>` or is it Node.js way? I'm getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token function` even when I `"use strict";`

Comment: This is only client side, so do it inside a `<script>` tag. This won't work in Node.

Comment: It doesn't let me use it in `<script>` tag. It's es6/7 as you said. As soon as I use `async` it throws an error.

Comment: async isn't available in any browser as of yet

Comment: I updated the answer to be a generator, yield + [bluebird coroutine](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html) operator, it's similar to how async/await works but can be used today but now you also need to include bluebird into your website

Comment: Just tried it and it downloads the files but produced `onefile.txt` is an empty file.

Comment: Maybe figured out what the error was... should be `!done && ...` can you test it?

Comment: Yeah, it works, but what am I supposed to do with the `intercept-me-nr...` and `/mitm.html?version=0.2.0` popping up?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121380/discussion-between-endless-and-vixing).